# tensorflow: multiply certain rows of a matrix with certain columns in another

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have a matrix `A` and a matrix `B`. I know `tf.matmul(A,B)` can calculate the multiplication of the two matrices. But I have a task that only requires multiplying certain rows of `A` with certain columns of `B`.

For example, I have a list of row ids of `A`, `Ls_A=[0,1,2]`, and a list of column ids of `B`, `Ls_B=[4,2,6]`. I want a result that is a list, denoted as `Ls`, such that:

```
Ls[0] = A[0,:] * B[:,4]
Ls[1] = A[1,:] * B[:,2]
Ls[2] = A[2,:] * B[:,6]
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b=tf.constant([[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[3,3,-1]])

#taking rows 0,1 from a, and columns 0,2 from b
ind_a=tf.constant([0,1])
ind_b=tf.constant([0,2])

r_a=tf.gather(a,ind_a)

#tf.gather access the rows, so we use it together with tf.transpose to access the columns
r_b=tf.transpose(tf.gather(tf.transpose(b),ind_b))

# the diagonal elements of the multiplication
res=tf.diag_part(tf.matmul(r_a,r_b))
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
print(r_a.eval())
print(r_b.eval())
print(res.eval())
```

This prints

```
#r_a
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]

#r_b
[[ 1  1]
 [ 1  2]
 [ 3 -1]]

#result
[12  8]
```

Comment: Thx. This is very close to what I expect. The only difference is that, in your example, I want a[0] * b[0], and a[1] * b[2]. That is, I only need the diagonal of your result. But given your solution, I think is quite easy to achieve my goal. I just need to perform tf.multiply(r_a,tf.transpose(r_b)), then perform a reduce_sum along axis 1. Is that right?

Comment: I missed the part that you wanted only the diagonal. You could use tf.diag_part for that. See my updated solution.